# Repeating field without using Matrix

Tags: custom-fields, fields, fieldtype

Has anyone got a way to create a "repeating" field without using Matrix?

I kind of need Matrix's ability to create new "rows" but since each row would just have a single bit of text using Matrix seems like overkill.

The data will just be text and I *could* simply let the user add a comma delimited list of items but for the sake of neatness I would prefer them to enter each item in its own textbox then click to add another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pixel and Tonic has another field_type called [P&T List](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pt-list) which might be suitable. If you just need a list of items, I'd look at that. I believe it's free.

Answer (score 4):

Nonprofit_tech's suggestion of P&T List is a good one. If that is too light-weight, then there is [**Grid Lite**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/grid-lite), which is a free, pared-down Matrix clone.

Comment: This is what I would suggest.

Answer (score 1):

[Nolan](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nolan) would probably do what you need in that case. My understanding is that it's a Matrix Clone with not as much functionality as Matrix does. I've not personally used it before, but Iain is a pretty solid developer, so I'd be confident in its function.

Comment: Nolan wouldn't work since it is a field type that goes inside a matrix allowing you to nest matrices.